# What is $a+b$ if $ x^2-y^2+11x+7y+18$ can be factorized as $(x+y+a)(x-y+b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If the polynomial $x^2-y^2+11x+7y+18$ can be factorized as $(x+y+a)(x-y+b)$ what is the value of $a+b$?

Observe that the expression can be rearranged with respect to  (x) and factorized as
\begin{align} x^2-y^2+11x+7y+18 &= x^2+11x-(y^2-7y-18) \\ &= x^2+11x-(y+2)(y-9) \\ &= (x+(y+2))(x-(y-9)) \\ &= (x+y+2)(x-y+9). \end{align}
This implies  (a=2) and  (b=9), hence  (a+b=11).

I don't understand how they got from step 2, 
$ \\ x^2+11x-(y+2)(y-9)\\$, to step 3,  $\\ (x+(y+2))(x-(y-9)) \\ $

https://brilliant.org/practice/algebraic-manipulation-rearranging/?problem=algebra-problem-56641&subtopic=advanced-polynomials&chapter=algebraic-manipulation

Comment: Expand $(a+x+y) (b+x-y)=x (a+b)+y (b-a)+a b+x^2-y^2$ and compare with the given polynomial $x^2-y^2+11x+7y+18$ and get $a+b=11$. In my opinion is much simpler...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  consider $x^2+11x-y^2+7y+18$ as a quadratic in $\,x\,$, then its discriminant is:

$$
\Delta = 11^2 - 4(-y^2+7y+18) = 4y^2-28y+49=(2y-7)^2
$$

The roots in $\,x\,$ are $x_{1,2}=\big(-11 \pm (2y-7)\big)/2\,$, then the quadratic factors as $(x-x_1)(x-x_2).$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: expand
$$
(x+y+a)(x-y+b)=x^2-y^2+(b+a)x+(b-a)y+ab
$$
Solve $b+a=11$ and $b-a=7$ to get $a=2$ and $b=9$. Luckily, $ab=18$.

---

**Errata**

I misread the question. We can stop once we notice that the coefficient of $x$ is $a+b$ to see that $a+b=11$.  No solving of simultaneous equations needs to be performed. However, solving the system does serve to verify that the factorization is actually correct.

Comment: Why would we need to solve the system? The question asks to find $a+b$, which should just be $11$ no?

Comment: @Ovi: Oh, I misread the question. I guess we don't need to solve the system at all. The coefficient of $x$ is $a+b$. However, it is nice to verify that the factorization actually works.

Answer (score 0):

You are familiar with the method of factoring $x^2 +11x +18$. You just need to answer the question "What two numbers multiply to $18$ and add up to $-11$?"

Now you have the polynomial $x^2+11x-(y+2)(y-9) = x^2+11x+(-y-2)(y-9)$. This is a quadratic in $x$, but instead of having constant coefficients, it's coefficients are functions of $y$. So we just need to answer the question "What two functions of $y$ multiply to $(-y-2)(y-9)$ and add up to $11$?" The answer is $-(-y-2)$ and $-(y-9)$, because $(-y-2)\cdot(y-9)=(-y-2)(y-9)$, and $-(-y-2)+[-(y-9)]=11$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple mathematical jugglery.
In $x^2+11x-(y+2)(y-9)$ write $11x$ as $9x+2x$ and add and subtract $xy$. Grouping the terms suitably you'll get the step following it.
i.e., 
\begin{align*}
x^2+11x-(y+2)(y-9)&= x^2+9x+2x-xy+xy-(y+2)(y-9)\\
&= x^2-x(y-9)+x(y+2)-(y+2)(y-9)\\
&= x(x-(y-9))+(y+2)(x-(y-9))\\
&= (x-(y-9))(x+y+2)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
(\overline{x+y}+a)(\overline{x-y}+b)&=(x+y)(x-y)+a(x-y)+b(x+x)+ab\\
&=x^2-y^2+(a+b)x-(a-b)y+ab\end{align}$$

Equating coefficients gives $a+b=11$.

Answer (score -1):

[The solution is on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTcrP.jpg) Simplify like this